# Default behaviour for a method in all sub classes

Tags: groovy

In my (statically compiled) Groovy application I build a tree-like data structure. That tree is built solely from instances of child classes that all share the same base class. Periodically I call an `update()` method of the root node, which calls `update()` of all its child nodes, and so forth, down to every leaf of the tree.

Let's say I have one `TreeNode` base class, and a bunch of sub classes, `ChildNode1`, `ChildNode2`, `ChildNode3`. The tree is built from those `ChildNode` classes, each class can occur multiple times in the tree (but as different instances).

Now I need to measure the total time spent in each `update()` method accumulated over each `ChildNode` class.

I don't want to measure the time directly in the beginning and end of each `update()` method, because I am writing a library and other devs might add more node classes based on `TreeNode`. I don't want to force them to do the time measuring on their own as well.

I hope it was clear what I want to achieve. Is there some way in (static) Groovy, something similar to decorations in Python maybe?

Comment: so you want to be able to intercept each and every call to update for each class that is and will ever be?  even outside e.g. an recursive call (tree calls update for each child VS child decides to updates itself)? have you considered an architectural approach like a final update method calling an abstract private update method?

Comment: There is ProxyMetaClass, which would allow you set an interceptor (BenchmarkInterceptor e.g.).  But this needs knowledge of the class.

Comment: Based on the feedback I got on the Groovy mailing list I might go with traits...

Comment: care to add some links here too?

Comment: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Default-behaviour-for-a-method-in-all-sub-classes-td5723206.html